# Changing the aspect ratio of a shape added using SceneBuilder

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Can I dynamically change the aspect ratio of a shape added using SceneBuilder?

It is like grabbing the four corners of a shape and dragging and dropping it.

SceneBuilder Extension document： https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/scene-builder/

---

The Edit2d Extension can be used to change the aspect ratio, but this seemed to be managed separately from the 3D model.

My goal is to detect members enclosed by shapes added using SceneBuilder.

Edit2d Extension document: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/edit2d-use/

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The aspect ratio is taken care of when you resize the window, you can check here: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-extensions/tree/main/public/extensions/DrawToolExtension

It's not possible to detect members enclosed by shapes added using SceneBuilder directly. You can use a raycaster, from the coordinates of scene builder objects, and find the objects enclosing, it may not be accurate though because the raycaster will give you all the objects intercepted.